# Bitmap Out Of Memory Error

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, bitmap

I want to save image to my image path that I got from database,But i get 'Out Of Memory' Error.What is it that i am doing incorrectly the following code?

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT imageColumn FROM PhotoTable WHERE id= :id";
cmd.ClearParameters();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":id", Id);
cmd.ExecuteDataReader();
if(cmd.DataReader.Read())
{  
   var lob = cmd.ExecuteReader().GetOracleLob(0);
   var image = new Bitmap(lob);
   picturebox1.Image = image;
   picturebox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
}
filePathName="c://image1.jpeg"//save path and file name 
var bm = new Bitmap(picturebox1.Image);
bm.Save(filePathName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Out of memory is a generic error from GDI+ (which `Bitmap` uses), not necessarily an actual out of memory condition. Most likely, the image is corrupted or in an unsupported format (or size or whatever). Try saving the bytes directly to disk (`File.WriteAllBytes`) and see what kind of file it is.

Comment: ...you will also get that error if *you* corrupted the image when you converted and saved it to the DB

Comment: You may not have write access to the root.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `Bitmap` each row. A bitmap must be Disposed. When you're not using a bitmap anymore, you should dispose it. You might create one bitmap for the picturebox and draw the bitmap from the database on it.

**PSEUDO:**

```
var pictureBoxBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, ....);
picturebox1.Image = pictureBoxBitmap;
picturebox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

using(Graphics pictureBoxGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBoxBitmap))  
{
    if(cmd.DataReader.Read())
    {  
       var lob = cmd.ExecuteReader().GetOracleLob(0);
       using(var image = new Bitmap(lob))
       {
            pictureBoxGraphics.DrawImage(..... image);
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
       }
   }
}
```

something like this.